# How to add a new array of keys to a JSON object in Angular (typescript)?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have tried looking for a solution, but the closest I cold find were with adding a simple key with a value...

So, I have this Json `object`:

```
 {
    "answers": [
      {
        "phrase": "Why?",
        "nextIntentId": "4a10fd2b-bc6b-4563-8d97-34ef6dec1ba9"
      },
      {
        "phrase": "Faster recovery?",
        "nextIntentId": "4f9eeecf-6477-435b-9f1b-43304748a4e5"
      }
    ],
    "intentId": "19f458e8-ce1f-43eb-beb8-b8ef4e7ff4c7"
  }
```

And I want to add an array to this object:
`"messages" : []`

The idea is, that afterwards I can `intent.messages.push(object)` objects to this array, just like in the `"answers" : []` array

```
 {
    "answers": [
      {
        "phrase": "Why?",
        "nextIntentId": "4a10fd2b-bc6b-4563-8d97-34ef6dec1ba9"
      },
      {
        "phrase": "Faster recovery?",
        "nextIntentId": "4f9eeecf-6477-435b-9f1b-43304748a4e5"
      }
    ],
    "intentId": "19f458e8-ce1f-43eb-beb8-b8ef4e7ff4c7",
    "messages" : []                            <<------------ I want to add this aray
  }
```

I have also tried `object.push('messages[]')` and got `Error: this.intent.push is not a function`

Thankyou for any kind of help in advance!

Comment: `intent.messages = []`? I'd strongly recommend reviewing basic JS before trying to stack TypeScript and the Angular APIs on top of it.

Comment: Thankyou, I will do that!

Comment: `intent.messages = []  //it may through compile error in angular 'as messages doesn't exist on object '`

`intent['messages'] = []`// error free`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value directly to a blank array:

`this.intent.messages = [];`